# Build de app extremamente lento

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Olá, estou com um sério problema com o tempo de Gradle Build de um aplicativo. Pesquisei muito a respeito, alterei configurações do gradle, desabilitei crashlytics, ativei daemon, cache de compilação, offline work e configuração sob demanda e nada, o build leva cerca de 13 minutos. Existe alguma outra forma que poderia reduzir esse tempo?

Comment: Tentou reinstalar tudo ? Não é a forma mais simples, mas em todo caso, quando não é um problema conhecido as vezes dá certo, mesmo sem ficar sabendo o porque depois. rs

Comment: Tu fala em reinstalar a IDE e o Gradle? Isso já foi feito sim.

Comment: @RBZ Apenas para complementar essa afirmação, há de facto vários cenários em que reinstalar é mais fácil que tentar corrigir. haha

Comment: @Isac Com certeza ! rs Reinstalar, reiniciar, etc ! rs Pra quem não tem tempo e pode fazer, é a ferramenta número 1 ! rs

Comment: @RBZ realmente em muitos casos é melhor mesmo, infelizmente nessa situação não resolveu :/

Comment: tente criar um projeto novo e fazer build pra ver se demora também. Se não demorar procure o que pode ser, talvez muitas dependências no `build.gradle`, ou alguma variável incorreta no `AndroidMainfest.xml` até ter pistas e achar o que é

Comment: Sem conhecer a estrutura do projeto é difícil rastrear a causa. Já tentou seguir as dicas da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#profile)? Em casos mais extremos o [gradle profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler) pode ajudar. Se estiver trabalhando com diversos módulos, [entender a diferença](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) entre `api` e `implementation` pode ajudar também.